# Why is one query with an extra join faster than the same query on normalized data (one less join)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I have two databases, each database contains data and 'labels' (indicated with *_p notation). In one database the labels are embedded with the data(stored in the table), in the other the labels are stored in a different table and thus a join is required to access the labels. For most queries the variant that uses embedded labels is faster, except for one query. I was wondering if someone could give me some insight into why this might be the case, I myself am not very familiar with the details of postgres, sql or databases in general? I list the 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE' output below. Thanks in advance.

The database is made up out of locations and users that are associated with those location points, data is label with *_p fields. The difference between the two databases is that in one the labels are embedded in the same table as the data and in the other they are stored in a different table thus requiring an extra join. Apart from this difference both queries do exactly the same thing. For most queries we see that the method with embedded labels is faster but for this particular query it is slower and I'd like to know why if it is possible. I am not really looking for a detailed answer I was just wondering if there was something obvious that caused one query plan to be slower than the other.

External labels query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, latitude, longitude 
FROM locations INNER 
   JOIN users ON locations.userid = users.id 
   JOIN users_p users0x ON users.id = users0x.users_id 
   JOIN locations_p locations0x ON locations.id = locations0x.locations_id 
WHERE country = ? AND date_part('year', age(birthdate)) > 18 
    AND (date_part('year', to_date(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2019) 
    AND (locations0x.longitude_p & '2') != 0 AND (users0x.lastname_p & '2') != 0 AND (users0x.firstname_p & '2') != 0 AND (users0x.birthdate_p & '2') != 0 AND (locations0x.timestamp_p & '2') != 0 
    AND (users0x.country_p & '2') != 0 AND (locations0x.latitude_p & '2') != 0
```

Explain analyze output:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..10116.71 rows=12 width=22) (actual time=317.811..331.306 rows=954 loops=1)
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..10051.48 rows=12 width=26) (actual time=317.793..328.701 rows=954 loops=1)
     Join Filter: (locations.userid = users0x.users_id)
     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 94446
     ->  Seq Scan on users_p users0x  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=96 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.051 rows=100 loops=1)
           Filter: (((country_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((birthdate_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((lastname_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((firstname_p & 2) <> 0))
     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..10030.23 rows=12 width=34) (actual time=0.000..3.209 rows=954 loops=100)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..10030.17 rows=12 width=34) (actual time=0.034..317.266 rows=954 loops=1)
                 Join Filter: (locations.userid = users.id)
                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 98382
                 ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..6.25 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.019..0.043 rows=2 loops=1)
                       Filter: ((country = 'Colombia'::text) AND (date_part('year'::text, age((('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp with time zone, (to_date(birthdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))::timestamp with time zone)) > '18'::double precision))
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 98
                 ->  Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..10008.30 rows=1250 width=16) (actual time=0.007..155.286 rows=49668 loops=2)
                       Filter: ((date_part('year'::text, (to_date("timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))::timestamp without time zone) >= '2010'::double precision) AND (date_part('year'::text, (to_date("timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))::timestamp without time zone) <= '2019'::double precision))
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 200332
 ->  Index Scan using locations_purpose_index on locations_p locations0x  (cost=0.42..5.43 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=954)
     Index Cond: (locations_id = locations.id)
     Filter: (((latitude_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((longitude_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((timestamp_p & 2) <> 0))
Planning time: 0.555 ms
Execution time: 331.449 ms
```

Embedded labels query:

```
 SELECT firstname, lastname, latitude, longitude 
 FROM locations INNER JOIN users ON locations.userid = users.id 
 WHERE country = ? AND date_part('year', age(birthdate)) > 18 
    AND (date_part('year', to_date(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2019) 
    AND (users.firstname_p & '2') != 0 
    AND (locations.timestamp_p & '2') != 0 
    AND (users.country_p & '2') != 0 AND (locations.longitude_p & '2') != 0 
    AND (locations.latitude_p & '2') != 0 
    AND (users.lastname_p & '2') != 0 AND (users.birthdate_p & '2') != 0
```

Explain analyze output:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..13782.09 rows=12 width=22) (actual time=0.113..421.690 rows=954 loops=1)
 Join Filter: (locations.userid = users.id)
 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 98382
 ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..8.25 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.062..0.087 rows=2 loops=1)
     Filter: ((country = 'Colombia'::text) AND ((country_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((birthdate_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((lastname_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((firstname_p & 2) <> 0) AND (date_part('year'::text, age((('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp with time zone, (to_date(birthdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))::timestamp with time zone)) > '18'::double precision))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 98
 ->  Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..13758.45 rows=1231 width=12) (actual time=0.018..207.065 rows=49668 loops=2)
     Filter: (((latitude_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((longitude_p & 2) <> 0) AND ((timestamp_p & 2) <> 0) AND (date_part('year'::text, (to_date("timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))::timestamp without time zone) >= '2010'::double precision) AND (date_part('year'::text, (to_date("timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))::timestamp without time zone) <= '2019'::double precision))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 200332
 Planning time: 0.811 ms
 Execution time: 421.820 ms
```

Comment: . . Without seeing the queries or examples of the data, no one is going to hazard a question.  This is especially true because you say the queries have no joins and yet both plans start with `nested loop` -- so a join is being executed anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for you feedback. I didn't know if it was relevant or not. I tried expanding the question with more information, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_part('year', age(birthdate)) > 18
(date_part('year', to_date(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2019)
```

Is first one even "right"?  It seems to ignore the month and day.  Consider taking the curdate, subtract 18 years, then comparing to `birthdate`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

The second one should not need to convert the timestamp at all.  Instead simply have date range literals that are compatible with it.

What's with the `& 2`?  That smells like a performance killer.

Then consider these composite indexes:

```
(country, birthdate)
(country, timestamp)
```